# How do I convert .c files to .gb (GameBoy) files on Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio, ubuntu-20.04, gameboy

I'm starting to learn how to program GameBoy games using Visual Studio on Ubuntu 20.04. This requires me to compile my .c file to .gb; on Windows this is done via .bat, but I cannot find an equivalent on Linux. Any ideas?

Comment: The .bat file is just a script, it certainly doesn't do a compilation step itself. You need to find out what it's calling behind the scenes. It's even possible that those tools don't exist for linux.

Comment: Damn... alright I'll switch to Windows for this. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

as I understand it, you need to use a make file to compile your C code. Ideally you could use GBDK (Game Boy Development Kit) and the github page has a description on how to use the make file. It basically has a set of instructions that brings together the various .h files and compiles them together.
If you are using Visual studio and coding directly in C without any of these resources then I'm not sure how you would do that.